# How to pass a Publisher to a class

Tags: swift, combine

I have a model class which holders a few publishers as the source of truth. And I also have a few classes that processes data. I need to process data depending on a publisher from the model class.

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var records = [Record]()
    let recordProcessor: RecordProcessor

    init() {
        ...
    }
}

class RecordProcessor: ObservableObject {
    @Published var results = [Result]()
}

struct RootView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MyView()
            .environmentObject(Model())
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(model.recordProcessor.results) { ... }
    }
}
```

`RecordProcessor` does a lot of work on records so the work is encapsulated into a class, but the input is the `records` stored on the `Model`. What is a proper way of passing in the `records` to the `RecordProcessor`?

Comment: Are you sure this is a good architecture? There is a model containing an ObservableObject - shouldn't be the other way around? Or maybe just the naming is confusing and this is not a model after all.

Comment: @pawello2222 I'm pretty sure this isn't the best architecture, that's probably why I'm unsure how to do it. It is a model, but one option I'm using is the `RecordProcessor` doesn't hold a @published, but returns a publisher which is stored back on the model. But with SwiftUI my main EnvironmentObject contains like 15 @Published variables because it's the top state. There must be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Record` is a value type, here is possible way (as far as I understood your goal)

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var records = [Record]() {
       didSet {
          recordProcessor.process(records)     // << something like this
       }
    }

    let recordProcessor: RecordProcessor

    init(processor: RecordProcessor) {
        self.recordProcessor = processor
    }
}

class RecordProcessor: ObservableObject {
    @Published var results = [Result]()

    func process(_ records: [Record]) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a good solution, it just seems off to me to have a @Published use a didSet. Mainly I'm not a fan of didSet, no good reason. I'm posted an answer of what I've gone with so far.

Answer (score 0):

The best I'm come up with is to have the `RecordProcessor` process the data and return a publisher with the results:

```
struct Record {}
struct Result {}

class Model: ObservableObject {

    @Published var records = [Record]()
    @Published var results = [Result]()

    let recordProcessor = RecordProcessor()
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
        $records
            .map(recordProcessor.process)
            .switchToLatest()
            .sink {
                self.results = $0
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}

class RecordProcessor: ObservableObject {

    func process(items: [Record]) -> AnyPublisher<[Result], Never> {
        return Just([]).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

}

struct RootView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MyView()
            .environmentObject(Model())
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(model.results) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will have a leak here, use `.sink { [weak self] in` and so on.

Comment: @Asperi Good call. I actually use this as the EnvironmentObject, so it's never released. Not trying to promote a bad practice :)